# message dialog with auto-multiline support?

Tags: swing

I'm using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` (and `showConfirmDialog` and other methods)
The problem with this method - it doesn't format text.
If i pass very long message - it will be dispalyed in one line (may be even wider then screen resolution).
Of course I can use `\n` in messages, but it would be extra-work for me.

I want a dialog which will format text for me automatically.

Answer (score 6):

> I want a dialog which will format text for me automatically.

Use HTML with CSS to limit the width.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelWidthTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String title = "<html><body style='width: 200px; padding: 5px;'>"
                    + "<h1>Do U C Me?</h1>"
                    + "Here is a long string that will wrap.  "
                    + "The effect we want is a multi-line label.";

                JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(title);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textLabel);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

> But if string is already multiline (contains one or more \n) it formats only first line of the string.

Replace all `\n` with `<br>` & `\n\n` with `<p>`.

> I lose "<" and ">" symbols. If string contains such symbols - they will not be displayed in the dialog

For`<` & `>`, translate them to the HTML equivalents, `&lt;` & `&gt;`.

Comment: hmm it only works for single-line strings. But if string is already multiline (contains one or more \n) it formats only first line of the string. How to format all lines?

Comment: another issue - I lose "<" and ">" symbols. If string contains such symbols - they will not be displayed in the dialog

Comment: overall it seems to complicated. I would prefer to create own Dialog with scrollable area inside.

Comment: LOL - that's what you were offered 2 days ago!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use just a plain old `JDialog` with a `JTextArea` inside it, something like:

```
JDialog editDialog = new JDialog();
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(myText);
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
JScrollPane areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
editDialog.add(areaScrollPane);
```

Comment: Then I will need to add Yes/No/Cancel buttons, process them by hand etc. etc. I would prefer to use `JOptionPane` or something else if possible...